# How to centre text but make them line up with each other

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p class="hi"><strong>Hello everyone I like to thankyou for helping me in advance</strong></p>
    <p class="hi"> test </p>
</div>
<p class="hi"> test </p>

.hi {
text-align: left;
}

.wrap {
text-align: center;
}
```

I want my text to be centered, but I want them to start off at the same place (left of the text aligned across the 2 `<p>` elements). I do not want to hardcode it if possible, for example like `margin: left 200px;`.

Comment: you want to text to center but also have the left of the text aligned across the 2 p elements?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: this would require a wrapper div around the p elements, center the p elements inside that wrapper and then align the text inside the p left

Comment: I tried that but it just moves everything to the left and is not longer center (check edit code in a minute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you wrap the text inside a `div` or any other *full-width* tag -`span` won't work for example, where the `div` is centered inside `p`, but the text is -by default- left aligned inside the `div`.

The problem with that is that you have to set a defined width for the `div`. Here I used 70%, but you can try to find the best for you design.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<p><div><strong> Hello everyone I like to thankyou for helping me in advance </strong></div></p>
  
  <p><div> test </div></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. If its fine for you then remove the borders

```css
.flex{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.paragraph{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:auto 20%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
 <div class="paragraph">
    <p><strong>Hello everyone I like to thankyou for helping me in advance</strong></p>
    <p> test </p>
 <div>
<div>
```